# Deploying AngularJS App: How to make app read JSON data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm stumped. So I've written a nice little web app that gets all its data from a JSON that has one array in it. To bridge the AngularJS-parts and the data, I have this line in my `services.js`

```
.constant("baseURL","http://localhost:3000/")
```

This of course only works with me locally. But I haven't considered that I might have to get my web host to serve up the data.

Now, I'm a complete beginner at this. I've managed to code my app with moderate effort, having only started coding in January. So I'm completely out of my league here. I don't even know what I'm looking for. I mean, I have to replace the `localhost:3000`with something. But if I do `http://domain.com/db.json` that obviously doesn't work.

I've talked to Godaddy's tech support and they go "Nuh-uh, not helping" the second I show them this line of code. Because, to be honest, I don't even know what the address I'm looking for is called. Is it a URI?

I have a few questions regarding this and I turn to you, because - this story gets worse - there's a possible job on the line for me. Not a coding thing, but the data that is parsed from the JSON into the site.

- What is the address I'm looking for called?
- How do I get my hosting to serve up JSON data? I mean, I don't even know what I need to ask the tech support people here. Do I need a JSON server?
- If they don't offer it, where could I get my JSON data served in a way that I can push more articles into the array and preferrably edit it, too?

Thank you so much!

### EDIT #1

If it helps, here's the contents of my /webroot/personalfolder

[image]

Comment: Your JSON is stored in a separate file yes?

Comment: @Harvey Yes. The file is called `db.json`.

Comment: You need to put the file in the same directory as your web application, and reference it in your application using the path to `db.json`. A better (more complicated) and safer way to do it would be to create a true DB, (MongoDB works great with `angular.js` coupled with a `node.js` backend. As far as the domain, you change that to the one you have purchased from godaddy.com

Comment: @EvanBechtol I would love to do a more sophisticated thing, but I'm afraid my skills aren't all that yet. I've pretty much exhausted my knowledge.

But you say I have to put the db.json into my scripts folder?

Comment: @Zeke You can put it there, or create a new folder called `db` and place the `db.json` there. The key thing here is that you get the path correct in your code. if you were to put the file in `scripts`, your path to the file in the code would be something like `./scripts/db.json`. (I don't know the exact file structure, so assuming `index.html` is in the root directory)

Answer (score 2):

1. You will need to change your `localhost:8000` to your **domain name**. For example, if you bought `www.foobar.com` then your base URL would just become `www.foobar.com` On a rented web server (like GoDaddy Hosting) ports 80 and 443 are normally open so you wouldn't need to specify this. If you are self hosting, you will need to open these ports on your router and apply port forwarding rules to your PC.
2. When you host your published website, you will just put your JSON file in with your Website Source. For example your structure may look like this:

`AngularAppFolder/index.html
                  js
                  csss`

Just add another folder called `db` place your JSON file in there, and reference it in your Angular code, no need to worry, **its just another file just like your HTML or CSS which makes up your website**. Remember though that your JSON data will be publicly available here!

3. If your looking for an alternative way of getting your JSON data, you may want to look into creating a **REST API**. This uses a web server to dish out data depenant on the HTTP request you send to it. but that's a very big topic! Here is some reading into it if your feeling brave! [Node.js REST API tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_restful_api.htm)

Final note: if you are self-hosting this application (running it on your own computer or server) then you will need to change the DNS record for your domain name to the global IP address of the server! you shouldn't have to worry if your using the hosting offerings from a company such as GoDaddy however.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `baseURL` value to whatever the URL on which the site is hosted. Something like `http://<mysite>.com`.

Comment: If I do that, I get an `Error -1`, which I don't know what that means. For reference, my db.json is in my site's root folder. So it's domain.com/db.json.

Comment: Where are you getting this Error -1?

Comment: When I add `domain.com` as the baseURL and then I reload the site. I have implemented error handling so that if data readout fails, it displays the error.

Comment: After you change the `baseURL`, do you load your `index.html` from `domain.com` or from `localhost`?

Comment: Is the site actually hosted at your domain location? So, its hosted on the correct web server that the DNS record for your domain points to?

Comment: @Harvey It is hosted in my domain's root. But not the hosting's root. Because I have a family who all have a Wordpress for something, the hosting is set up like this /webroot/personalfolder/ and so the path to db.json, index.html etc would be /webroot/personalfolder/db.json. Does that help?

Comment: Okay, so if you have multiple sites on the same domain name you will need your baseURL pointing to the base of your site... for example `www.foobar.com/yourfolder` but depending on how your hosting is setup, if a user typed 'www.foobar.com' into their browser, it would not load your page they would need to type `www.foobar.com/yourfolder`

Comment: @Harvey To access my site, you can either type `http://foobar.com/personalfolder` or `personaldomain.com`. Would it maybe help if I got Godaddy's IP or something?

Comment: No. so if your site is accessed at `http://foobar.com/personalfolder` THAT is your base URL. make the additional changes noted in my post, (JSON speciffic) and obviously copy the files over and you should be all set